# Define 2 plotted lines in an image as variables inside a function in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, plot, image-segmentation

[image: PRODUCT OF CODE]

```
Function [Yupper, Ylower] = Segmentation(A)
        A=imread('g16.BMP');
        AR=A(:,:,1);
        [rows, columns] = size(AR);
        avgs = mean(AR(50:165,:), 2);
        avgs2 = mean(AR(165:315,:), 2);
        [~,ind]= max(abs(diff(avgs)));
        [~,ind2]= max(abs(diff(avgs2)));
        figure, image(AR,'CDataMapping','scaled'); colormap('gray'); hold on;
        Yupper=plot([1 size(AR,2)], [ind+50 ind+50], 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
        Ylower=plot([1 size(AR,2)], [ind2+165 ind2+165], 'g', 'LineWidth', 2);
    end
```

Above is code used to segment grey scale images based on large instensity changes,I'm looking to declare the 2 plotted lines as variables so I can carry out future processing. However, If I type in **whos** , the lines appear as follows in the table;

```
YL               1x1                     112  matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Line              
YU               1x1                     112  matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Line
```

if I remove the the plot commands I receive errors associated with brackets etc and if I manipulate the code any further it seems to mess up the correctly plotted data, can anyone help?

Comment: Yupper and Ylower are figure handles, used by matlab to access with the ccode to the figure, not the plot lines!

Comment: Im trying  to define Yupper before plotting now and I still can't get it right ... `Yupper=([ind+50 ind+50]:[1 size(AR,2)]);`

Comment: What is exactly that you want? A pixelated line? Or just the line?

Comment: I want to be able to plot the line initially so i can display separation of segments and then remove the line for feature extraction purposes as the 2 lines define an important region....

Comment: Sorry, you need to be a bot more specific. You want the lines to be plotted and then removed from the figure? There is a `pause` or something that stops the code in the middle of the two events so a human can actually see that?

Comment: Plus, what matlab version are you using? I am guessing 2014b or higher?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to delete specific data for a figure you can do it accessing the `Xdata` and `Ydata` properties of the figure handle. You can do it in Matlab R2014a or older by:

```
set(YL,'XData',[])
set(YL,'YData',[])
```

or in Matlab R2014b or newer by:

```
YL.XData=[];
YL.YData=[];
```

Example in R2013b:

```
clear;clc;

y=rand(20,1)*20;
x=1:20;
img=rand(20,20);

figure
hold on
image(img,'CDataMapping','scaled'); colormap('gray');
hp=plot(x,y);

% emulating your code delay
pause(2);
set(hp,'XData',[])
set(hp,'YData',[])
```

Comment: Hi, iv added a picture to the original question to demonstrate a better understanding of what Im trying to achieve, so once this important segment is define I'm looking to remove it for feature extraction to plot histograms etc. since it is secluded region in an image , what I planned to do was create a new vector Z by stacking all columns with in that area on top on one another by:

Comment: `z=[];
for i = 1:1:1024
      z=[z  X(i,yL(i) : 1 : yU(i))]
  end;`

Comment: this is the reason Im looking to define the segments as Yupper and Ylower

Comment: @SeánMcNeill You are being more unclear every time you say someting.... Can you make an SPECIFIC question about an SPECIFIC problem you have>

Comment: instead of using `plot([1 size(AR,2)], [ind+50 ind+50], 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);` to plot Yupper, how do I define Yupper initially the same as above using a line of code similar to ..  `Yupper=([ind+50 ind+50]:[1 size(AR,2)]);` so in future I can simply plot Yupper using `plot(Yupper);`

Comment: I am not sure you can do that. however, whats the problem of saving literally 4 point in a variable? @SeánMcNeill

Comment: errors as such appear when I try to carry out further processing:

Comment: `Undefined function 'colon' for input arguments of type 'matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Line'.`